# Indices: Negatives and fractions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to rewrite this expression using powers -

[image]

Rewrite these expressions as a power of the given number:

[image]

I know that a reciprocal of a power is when it halves.

e.g. $2^0$ $=1$

$2^{-1}$ $= 0.5$

Comment: Negative of a power means "take the reciprocal".  Fractional powers are a way of expressing roots.

Comment: if you need a refresher on exponent rules take a look at http://mathontrack.comze.com/exponentials2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(36)^{-\dfrac52}=(6^2)^{-\dfrac52}=6^{-5}$$

If $\displaystyle\dfrac1{x^3}=x^y, 1=x^3\cdot x^y=x^{3+y}$

$\displaystyle\implies x^{3+y}=1=x^0\iff 3+y=0$ for real $x\ne0$

**Reference** : [Exponent Combination Laws](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws)